# NetSuite drivers aren't working with MariaDB on Ubuntu 22.04: can't open lib 'opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so'

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, odbc, netsuite, unixodbc

I'm trying to use the CONNECT engine in MariaDB to access NetSuite. I have the ODBC drivers installed and working with everything except MariaDB. Every time I try, I get this error:

`ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 174 'SQLDriverConnect: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so' : file not found' from CONNECT`

I'm using MariaDB 10.11.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I've checked that everything is 64-bit.  I've done multiple purges and installs and restarts. I tried downgrading to MariaDB 10.6 (the version in the Ubuntu repository).  Pyodbc and isql are connecting perfectly.  It's only failing with MariaDB.

I've tried everything I can find and nothing is working.  I'll dump everything relevant below.  I'll take any suggestions at this point.  It's still near the beginning of the project, so switching databases or even Linux distributions is still on the table.  If anyone has successfully connected to NetSuite from a SQL database on Linux, please share.

Thanks.

ldd:

```
/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64$ ldd ivoa27.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffb35a7000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb700afc000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb700af7000)
        libicuuc.so.42 => /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/libicuuc.so.42 (0x00007fb700400000)
        libicudata.so.42 => /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/libicudata.so.42 (0x00007fb6ff300000)
        libpam.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x00007fb700ae5000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb700ade000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb6ff0d6000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb6fefef000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb700abe000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb6fedc7000)
        libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007fb7006d2000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb700b0a000)
        libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x00007fb700ab4000)
```

/etc/environment:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64"
ODBCINI="/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbc64.ini"
OASDK_ODBC_HOME="/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64"
```

/etc/odbc.ini:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
NetSuite=NetSuite ODBC Drivers 8.1

[NetSuite]
Driver=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so
Description=Connect to your NetSuite account
Host=3989691.connect.api.netsuite.com
Port=1708
ServerDataSource=NetSuite2.com
Encrypted=1
AllowSinglePacketLogout=1
Truststore=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/cert/ca3.cer
CustomProperties=AccountID=3989691;RoleID=1015

[ODBC]
Trace=0
IANAAppCodePage=4
TraceFile=odbctrace.out
TraceDll=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ddtrc27.so
InstallDir=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC Drivers]
NetSuite ODBC Drivers 8.1=Installed
UsageCount=1

[NetSuite ODBC Drivers 8.1]
APILevel=1
ConnectFunctions=YYN
Driver=ivoa27.so
DriverODBCVer=03.52
FileUsage=0
SQLLevel=1
UsageCount=1
```

isql with results:

```
isql 'NetSuite' 'user' 'password'
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

A python test file:

```
import pyodbc

try:
    connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=NetSuite; UID=user; PWD=password')
except e:
    print(e)
else:
    print("Success!")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("[SQL statement]")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row:
        print(row)
```

Python results:

```
python3 test_ns.py
Success!
[SQL results]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things this error could possibly mean:

1. the user mariadb runs as (a service user like `mysql`) may not have permissions to the ivoa27.so path or its parents.  Make sure it does.
2. the environment variables that you have already set in /etc/environment may not be available to the mariadb serviceunit.  you may have to manually edit that service unit and daemon-reload systemd after adding the necessary `Environment=` parameters to the service unit.
3. mariadb connect also allows use of [jdbc jar files and some configuration values](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-system-variables/).  You may find it easier to go that route rather than dealing with os-level dependencies.

Comment: **1)** I ran `sudo -u mysql test -x /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so && echo $?` and got 0, so it has permission.  It also has read, but not write, permission.   

**2)** I did `sudo systemctl edit mariadb` and added `Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=..."` etc.  Didn't help.    

**3)** I'll have to configure Java and try that.  At the moment Java is not installed on this system.

Comment: Did you also set the ODBCINI and OASDK_... environment variables?

Comment: Yes.  Here's the full line: `Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64" "ODBCINI=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbc64.ini" "OASDK_ODBC_HOME=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64"`

Comment: This might be worth another question, but I hit a snag configuring Java.  When I do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'connect%'`, I don't have connect_class_path, connect_java_wrapper, or connect_jvm_path.  I'm back in Mariadb 10.6.  Those should be there, right?